# Reapplying for a visa

Tags: visas

If I am going to theUS to participate in a event, selected by the Indian government, and my visa application is rejected, are there any chances of getting the visa from a different consulate after 3 days?

Comment: Your chances are slim and none and barring something akin to a miracle you'll only find yourself out of more visa fees. Don't do it. When I was coming to represent my country in Washington DC twenty one years ago, visa issues with the US embassy were handled by a government protocol officer although I had to show up for the interview. That's how yours should ideally be handled.

Comment: You can only get approved by learning why your visa was refused, and addressing the reasons for refusal.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely. Where several consulates exist they usually have distinct geographical areas of responsibility. You're likely to be referred back to the original consulate.

Even if you're not, they have access to the same records and operate under the same rules. Unless you address the reasons for refusal you'll be refused again.

Comment: If the second consulate doesn't just refer the OP back to the original consulate, not only will the probably come to the same conclusion, they might also ban the OP from applying for a visa, or at least add a note to his/her record.